# Using mutex in mixed C/C++ with portability to Linux and Windows environments

Tags: linux, windows, pthreads, mutex, msys2

How to share a mutex between C++ and C proper working for Windows and Linux.

First I used pthread which worked fine under Linux and Windows Cygwin (only used in the C++ files).
Then I switched to MSYS2 which seems to have problems with pthread. But changing to std::thread is easy.
But how to share a mutex?

I want to get rid of pthread but I think it is not possible to include std::mutex in C file.

Comment: To be clear, you are looking for an approach to sharing a mutex between two source files in the same process which are written in different languages, and the approach must be portable to other operating systems by simply rebuilding without source code changes?  The other interpretation of your question is that you are looking for a way to share mutexes between processes (a common IPC task) over the network (no longer a common IPC task), and the machines sharing a single mutex are not all running the same OS.

Comment: In particular, what you said you've tried is consistent with the first interpretation (within a process, works on one OS at a time), but the phrase "mixed Linux/Windows environment" in the title suggests the second interpretation.  So an edit for clarity would be good.

Comment: *"MSYS2 which seems to have problems with pthread"* Can you elaborate?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The first interpretation is correct. The code should run on Windows/Linux (e.g. for extensive continous integration). No network connection is involved. A common task I think?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I am suffering problems by closing threads when linking against pthread under MSYS2 and after launching the program in Windows. After a bit of googling I found it would be best to you std::thread to be interoperatable between different systems.

Comment: On which [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) does that happen?

Comment: MSYS2 MinGW x64

Comment: @MKFein, if you want to use `std::thread` from C then in principle you could do so with the help of wrapper functions written in C++ and declared with C linkage.  You might need to engage in some pointer casting in conjunction with this to give the C code a handle on the mutexes involved or the objects containing them.

Comment: @MKFein: Based on your confirmation, I've edited your title to remove mention of "mixed Linux/Windows", since you only need it to work separately on each.

Comment: @MKFein Can you show a code example that demonstrates the problem? See [mcve]

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sadly I am not able to reproduce the behaviour nor to restore the described state. Maybe an error on my side.